# Check if any of the selected cells is ReadOnly In a WPf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a grid that has both editable and read-only cells. On selection of cells, if at least one cell is editable (not read-only) I have to enable Cut and Paste icons from the toolbar.

I have bound the `IsEnabled` property of Cut/Paste icons to a property `CanPerformCutPaste`.

This is the code that is currently working.

```
private void dataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
   CanPerformCutPaste = dataGrid.SelectedCells.Any(c => !GetDataGridCell(c, dataGrid).IsReadOnly);
}


public static DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo, DataGrid grid)
{
       if (cellInfo == null || grid == null)
          return null;

       grid.ScrollIntoView(cellInfo.Item as DataRowView, cellInfo.Column);
       var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
       if (cellContent != null)
          return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

       return null;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality? I don't want this to result in a performance issue for large number of cells.

**Edit:** 
The columns are never set to read-only. Only some cells based on a condition are read-only. Therefore the column property cannot be checked.

Comment: Usually, you set only full columns readonly or editable. If this is the case, you can simply use the Column-property of the DataGridCellInfo, and check whether it's readonly.

Comment: There are columns with both read-only and editable cells.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to check the last selected Cell, instead of checking all the selected cells each time, and besides checking the column property of the selected cell is enough, here a simple example:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Copy/Past" Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPerformCutPaste}"></Button>
    <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="Dg" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectedCellsChanged="Dg_OnSelectedCellsChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>                  
</Grid>
```

and the SelectedCellsChanged handler:

```
   private void Dg_OnSelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Dg.SelectedCells.Any())             
        CanPerformCutPaste = Dg.SelectedCells.Last().Column.IsReadOnly;
    }
```

Ps: I am sure you know that the vm should implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface

```
private bool _canPerformCutPaste  ;
    public bool CanPerformCutPaste
    {
        get
        {
            return _canPerformCutPaste;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_canPerformCutPaste == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _canPerformCutPaste = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have columns where some cells from the same column are read-only and some are editable. I don't think I can use the last cell either. If a previously selected cell was editable, Cut should still be enabled (even if the last selected cell is read-only)

Comment: I see, can't you then use the condition that mark a cell as ReadOnly to enable or disable the c/p button ?